# android : change tab and pager with button event in pager slidding tab strip

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, pagerslidingtabstrip

i use pager sliding tab strip in my app , i want to change tab and pager with button event how can i do that ? 
i use this code but it`s not work

```
public class CheckoutMethod_Fragment extends Fragment {

private static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";

private int position;
private Button btn_continue;
ViewPager pager;


public static CheckoutMethod_Fragment newInstance(int position) {
    CheckoutMethod_Fragment f = new CheckoutMethod_Fragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);
    f.setArguments(b);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    position = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION); 
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_checkout_method__fragment,
            container, false);

    final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter_PlaceCartOrder(getFragmentManager()));

    btn_continue = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button_continue);
    btn_continue.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //Replace right fragment with another fragment

            pager.setCurrentItem(2);
        }
    });
    return v;
}}
```

---

and this is ViewPagerAdapter_PlaceCartOrder

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter_PlaceCartOrder extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final String[] TITLES = { "Checkout Method","bbbb", "aaa ","ggg", "Order Review" };

public ViewPagerAdapter_PlaceCartOrder(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return TITLES[position];
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return TITLES.length;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {

    case 0:
        return CheckoutMethod_Fragment.newInstance(position);
    case 1:
        return CustomerInformation_Fragment.newInstance(position);
    case 2:
        return BillingInformation_Fragment.newInstance(position);
    case 3:
        return ShippingInformation_Fragment.newInstance(position);
    case 4:
        return ShippingMethod_Fragment.newInstance(position);
    case 5:
        return PaymentInformation_Fragment.newInstance(position);
    case 6:
        return OrderReview_Fragment.newInstance(position);
    case 7:
        return CheckoutMethod_Fragment.newInstance(position);
    case 8:
        return CheckoutMethod_Fragment.newInstance(position);
    case 9:
        return CheckoutMethod_Fragment.newInstance(position);
    default:
        return SuperAwesomeCardFragment.newInstance(6000);
    }

    // return SuperAwesomeCardFragment.newInstance(position);
}}
```

---

```
public class PlaceOrderActivity extends FragmentActivity {

ViewPager pager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_order);

    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/Yekan.ttf");

    // Initialize the ViewPager and set an adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter_PlaceCartOrder(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    //pager.setCurrentItem(7);

    // Bind the tabs to the ViewPager
    PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
    tabs.setIndicatorColor(Color.rgb(225, 19, 18));
    tabs.setIndicatorHeight(3);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.place_order, menu);
    return true;
}

public void ChangeFragment(){
    pager.setCurrentItem(2);
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1. The `final View v` in the `onCreateView` is shadowed by the `View v` being passed as an argument of the `onClick` method.
2. You need to setup pager before you can use it. At present, you are setting it up in the `onClick` method. You need to move the pager setup code to the `onCreateView` method.

Comment: i move setup code to onCreateView but it`s return error for this line : pager.setAdapter(new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));

Comment: how can i slove problem first problem ?\

Comment: If you have moved pager setup to `onCreateView`, you may not need to solve the 1st. But if you insist, renaming the argument from `View v` to `View view` will do the trick. If you can post your new code, it may be possible to point out the error.

Comment: What error do you get? Post the implementation of `ViewPagerAdapter_PlaceCartOrder` as well.

Comment: i post ViewPagerAdapter_PlaceCartOrder

Comment: it`s return java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Only reason for a NPE on that line is if you don't have a `ViewPager` with id `pager` in `activity_checkout_method__fragment`.

Comment: i post main activity too , that code work on main activity but it return NPE error on fragment !